# How to set field value based on table cell changed value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input fields with label empID and Name and table with 3 columns tblempID, tblName and tblTxt.
How to set empID value to be the same tblmpID value when any tblTxt cell value changed in each row in table.

T tried the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 tblTxtchange();
  
  $('.tbl1').on('change', tblTextchange);
  
  function tblTxtchange() {
    $('.tbl1 tbody tr').each(function () {
      $(this).find('.tblTxt').each(function () {
        $('.tblTxt').change(function(){           
          $('.empID').val($('.tblText')
          .closest('tr').find($('.tblEmpID').val()));
        });
      });
    });
  }

});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<input id="empID"/>
<input id="Name"/>

<table style="width:100%" class="tbl1">
  <tr>
    <th>tblempID</th>
    <th>tblName</th> 
    <th>tblTxt</th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input class="tblEmpID" /></td>
    <td><input class="tblName" /></td>
    <td><input class="tblTxt" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="tblEmpID" /></td>
    <td><input class="tblName" /></td>
    <td><input class="tblTxt" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="tblEmpID" /></td>
    <td><input class="tblName" /></td>
    <td><input class="tblTxt" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're overthinking it.  (You're also using `.find()` incorrectly.)  At its simplest, you want a handler for `.tblTxt` elements which finds the corresponding `tblEmpID` value and sets it to the `#empID` element.  There's no need for loops, function calls, etc.  Something like this:

```
$('.tblTxt').on('change', function () {
    let empID = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tblEmpID').val();
    $('#empID').val(empID);
});
```

Comment: I already tried this at first but it works only for first row, that is why i tried to use .each()  to loop for each row.

Comment: @M.Gooda: Sounds like you did something else wrong then.  This works: https://jsfiddle.net/2moa19Lt  You don't need to loop over your matching elements in jQuery to set handlers to them, jQuery does that automatically when the selector finds multiple elements.

Comment: Yes it working, the class name was not correct, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have a running code for your problem please update if you are looking for something else

```
$('.tblTxt').change(function () {
  var row_emp_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tblEmpID').val();
  $('#empID').val(row_emp_id);
});
```